# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then which is larger: $D(p^k)$ or $D(m^2)$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ to be $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.  Finally, denote the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Here is my question:

> **If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then which is larger: $D(p^k)$ or $D(m^2)$?**

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $p$ is prime, we have
$$1<I(p^k)=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k (p - 1)}<\frac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p - 1)}=\frac{p}{p-1}.$$
Now, because $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have the lower bound $p \geq 5$, whereupon we obtain the upper bound
$$I(p^k)<\frac{p}{p-1} \leq \frac{5}{4}.$$
Note that, since $p^k m^2$ is perfect and $\gcd(p,m)=1$, then we have
$$2=I(p^k m^2)=I(p^k)I(m^2) \iff I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)}.$$
This implies that we have the lower bound
$$I(m^2) > \frac{2}{(5/4)} = \frac{8}{5},$$
from which we finally get
$$1 < I(p^k) < \frac{5}{4} < \frac{8}{5} < I(m^2) < 2,$$
since $m^2$ is a proper factor of the perfect number $p^k m^2$, and is therefore *deficient*.

In particular, we have
$$0 < 2 - I(m^2) < 2 - I(p^k) < 1$$
$$0 < \frac{D(m^2)}{m^2} < \frac{D(p^k)}{p^k} < 1$$
$$0 < D(m^2) < \frac{m^2}{p^k}\cdot{D(p^k)} < m^2.$$

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

Comment: I know that $p^k < m^2$, but I do not know of any upper bound for the quantity $$\frac{m^2}{p^k}.$$

Comment: $D$ is $\sigma_0$, the number of divisors, isn't it?

Comment: @ajotatxe:  Thank you for your time and attention.  $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of $x$, as defined near the beginning of the question.

Comment: @ajotatxe: The deficiency of the first so-and-so integers are tabulated in [OEIS sequence A033879](http://oeis.org/A033879).

Comment: Lastly, notice that $D(p^k) \neq D(m^2)$, as $D(m^2)$ is evidently odd, while $D(p^k)$ is even, because of
$$\sigma(p^k) = 1 + \ldots + p^k \equiv (k + 1) \pmod 4,$$
since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, and
$$\sigma(p^k) \equiv (k+1) \pmod 4 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$$
since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful, but one can prove that
$$D(m^2)\lt D(p^k)\iff m^2\lt \frac{(p^{k+1}-1)(p^{k+1}-2p^k+1)}{2(p-1)(p^k-1)}$$

Comment: Would you mind sharing more details on how you proved that biconditional, @mathlove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to comment :

One can prove that
$$D(m^2)\lt D(p^k)\iff m^2\lt \frac{(p^{k+1}-1)(p^{k+1}-2p^k+1)}{2(p-1)(p^k-1)}$$

*Proof* :

We have
$$\begin{align}&D(p^k)-D(m^2)
\\\\&=2p^k-\sigma(p^k)-2m^2+\sigma(m^2)
\\\\&=2p^k-\sigma(p^k)-2m^2+\frac{2p^km^2}{\sigma(p^k)}
\\\\&=2p^k-\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}-2m^2+\frac{2p^km^2(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}
\\\\&=\frac{(p-1)(p^{k+1}-1)(2p^k-2m^2)-(p^{k+1}-1)^2+2p^km^2(p-1)^2}{(p-1)(p^{k+1}-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{ p^{2 k + 2}- 2 p^{2 k + 1}  + 2 p^k - 1-2(p^{k + 1} - p^k  - p +1)m^2}{(p-1)(p^{k+1}-1)}
\\\\&=\frac{(p^{k+1}-1)(p^{k+1}-2p^k+1)-2(p-1)(p^k-1)m^2}{(p-1)(p^{k+1}-1)}\end{align}$$
from which we get
$$\begin{align}D(m^2)\lt D(p^k)&\iff \frac{(p^{k+1}-1)(p^{k+1}-2p^k+1)-2(p-1)(p^k-1)m^2}{(p-1)(p^{k+1}-1)}\gt 0
\\\\&\iff (p^{k+1}-1)(p^{k+1}-2p^k+1)\gt 2(p-1)(p^k-1)m^2
\\\\&\iff m^2\lt \frac{(p^{k+1}-1)(p^{k+1}-2p^k+1)}{2(p-1)(p^k-1)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove!  +1 =)

Comment: Conjecturally, $k=1$ ought to hold (and this is now known as the *Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture* on odd perfect numbers), and this is known to imply $p < m$ ([Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591)).

Comment: So granted $k=1$ holds unconditionally, we get a contradiction, as follows:

$$p^2 < m^2 < \frac{(p^2 - 1)(p^2 - 2p + 1)}{2(p - 1)^2} = \frac{p^2 - 1}{2},$$

which finally results in $p^2 + 1 < 0$.  **QED.**  Hence, we have the implication

$$k = 1 \implies D(p^k) < D(m^2).$$

Comment: Accepting your answer now, @mathlove, as it definitely sheds light on the problem at hand.  Thanks again!  =)