# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then which is larger: $D(p^k)$ or $D(m)$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Preamble:  This question is tangentially related to this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4162615).)

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ to be $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.  Finally, denote the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Dris conjectured in [(Dris (2008))](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) and [(Dris (2012))](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) that the inequality $p^k < m$ always holds.  Brown was the first one to prove in a preprint [(Brown (2016))](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) that the weaker inequality $p < m$ holds in general.  However, [recent evidence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4170595) suggests that the Dris Conjecture that $p^k < m$ may in fact be false.  (If we could rule out or show that $m < p^k$ follows from the remaining two cases in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4170595), then we will have a disproof for both the Dris Conjecture and the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$.)

Here is my question:

> **If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then which is larger: $D(p^k)$ or $D(m)$?**

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $p$ is prime, we have
$$1<I(p^k)=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k (p - 1)}<\frac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p - 1)}=\frac{p}{p-1}.$$
Now, because $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, we have the lower bound $p \geq 5$, whereupon we obtain the upper bound
$$I(p^k)<\frac{p}{p-1} \leq \frac{5}{4}.$$
Note that, since $p^k m^2$ is perfect and $\gcd(p,m)=1$, then we have
$$2=I(p^k m^2)=I(p^k)I(m^2) \iff I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)}.$$
This implies that we have the lower bound
$$I(m^2) > \frac{2}{(5/4)} = \frac{8}{5},$$
from which we finally get
$$1 < I(p^k) < \frac{5}{4} < \frac{8}{5} < I(m^2) < 2,$$
since $m^2$ is a proper factor of the perfect number $p^k m^2$, and is therefore *deficient*.

But we know that
$$I(p^k) < \dfrac{5}{4} < \sqrt{\dfrac{8}{5}}< \sqrt{I(m^2)} < I(m) < I(m^2) < 2$$

In particular, we have
$$0 < 2 - I(m) < 2 - I(p^k) < 1$$
$$0 < \dfrac{D(m)}{m} < \dfrac{D(p^k)}{p^k} < 1$$
$$0 < D(m) < \frac{m}{p^k}\cdot{D(p^k)} < m.$$

We therefore have the implication
$$m < p^k \implies D(m) < D(p^k).$$

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

Comment: FYI, using $I(m) < I(m^2)$, one can get $$\dfrac{D(p^k)}{2-\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}}\le m\implies D(m)\gt D(p^k).$$

Comment: Similarly, using $(I(m^2))^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < I(m)$, one can get$$m\le \dfrac{D(p^k)}{2-\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^{\frac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}}}\implies D(m)\lt D(p^k)$$ which is better than $m < p^k \implies D(m) < D(p^k)$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I would be highly interested to see a proof of your second implication.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long to comment* :

Let $c:=\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}$. Using $(I(m^2))^{c} < I(m)$, one can get
$$m\le \dfrac{D(p^k)}{2-\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^{c}}\implies D(m)\lt D(p^k)\tag1$$
which is better than $$m < p^k \implies D(m) < D(p^k).$$

*Proof* :

$(I(m^2))^c\lt I(m)$ is equivalent to
$$\bigg(\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{m^2}\bigg)^c\lt\frac{\sigma(m)}{m}\iff \sigma(m)\gt m\bigg(\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{m^2}\bigg)^c=m\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^c$$
Using $\sigma(m)\gt m\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^c$, we get

$$D(p^k)-D(m)=D(p^k)-2m+\sigma(m)\gt D(p^k)-2m+m\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^c$$

So, we can say that if
$$D(p^k)-2m+m\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^c\ge 0\tag2$$
then $D(m)\lt D(p^k)$ where note that
$$(2)\iff m\le \frac{D(p^k)}{2-\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^c}$$ So, we can say that $(1)$ holds.

To see that $(1)$ is better than $m < p^k \implies D(m) < D(p^k)$,  it is sufficient to prove that
$$p^k\lt \frac{D(p^k)}{2-\bigg(\dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}\bigg)^{c}}\tag3$$

We have
$$\begin{align}(3)&\iff p^k\lt \frac{p^{k+1}-2p^k+1}{(p-1)\bigg(2-\bigg(\dfrac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}\bigg)^c\bigg)}
\\\\&\iff p^k(p-1)\bigg(2-\bigg(\frac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}\bigg)^c\bigg)\lt p^{k+1}-2p^k+1
\\\\&\iff 2-\bigg(\frac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}\bigg)^c\lt \frac{p^{k+1}-2p^k+1}{p^k(p-1)}
\\\\&\iff \bigg(\frac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}\bigg)^c\gt 2-\frac{p^{k+1}-2p^k+1}{p^k(p-1)}
\\\\&\iff \bigg(\frac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}\bigg)^c\gt \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)}
\\\\&\iff \frac{2p^k(p-1)}{p^{k+1}-1}\gt \bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k(p-1)}\bigg)^{1/c}
\\\\&\iff 2\gt \bigg(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^{k}(p-1)}\bigg)^{(c+1)/c}
\\\\&\iff 2^{c/(c+1)}\gt \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^{k}(p-1)}
\\\\&\iff 2^{c/(c+1)}p^k(p-1)-p^{k+1}+1\gt 0
\\\\&\iff p^k\underbrace{\bigg((2^{c/(c+1)}-1)p-2^{c/(c+1)}\bigg)}_{\text{positive}}+1\gt 0\end{align}$$
which does hold. So, $(3)$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

Following [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967)'s hint in the comments, I obtain:

Assume that
$$\dfrac{D(p^k)}{2 - \dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}} \leq m.$$

This implies that
$$\dfrac{D(p^k)}{2 - I(m^2)} \leq m$$
$$\implies \dfrac{D(p^k)}{\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2}} \leq m$$
$$\implies \dfrac{m^2 D(p^k)}{D(m^2)} \leq m$$
$$\implies mD(p^k) \leq D(m^2)$$
$$\implies D(p^k) \leq \dfrac{D(m^2)}{m}$$

But we obtain from
$$I(m) < I(m^2) \iff 2 - I(m^2) < 2 - I(m) \iff \dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} < \dfrac{D(m)}{m} \iff \dfrac{D(m^2)}{m} < D(m).$$

We conclude that
$$\dfrac{D(p^k)}{2 - \dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}} \leq m \implies D(p^k) < D(m).$$

**QED**

*Additional Considerations*

When the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture that $k=1$ holds, then
$$\dfrac{D(p^k)}{2 - \dfrac{2}{I(p^k)}} = \dfrac{p - 1}{2 - \dfrac{2p}{p+1}} = \dfrac{p^2 - 1}{2}.$$